# Keras summation Layer acting weird, summing over training set

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am having trouble understanding the basic way Keras works. I am experimenting with a single summation layer, implemented as a Lambda layer using tensorflow as a backend:

```py
from keras import backend as K

test_model = Sequential()
test_model.add( Lambda( lambda x: K.sum(x, axis=0), input_shape=(2,3)) )

x = np.reshape(np.arange(12), (2,2,3))
test_model.predict(x)
```

This returns:

```
array([[  6.,   8.,  10.],
   [ 12.,  14.,  16.]], dtype=float32)
```

Which is very weird, as it sums over the first index, which to my understanding corresponds to the index of the training data. Also, if I change the axis to `axis=1` then the sum is taken over the second coordinate, which is what I would expect to get for `axis=0`.

What is going on? Why does it seem like the `axis` chosen effects how the data is passed to the lambda layer?

Comment: Also, I'll be glad if someone could point to a reference which explains how keras works in general. all I could find are many examples, or alternatively detailed documentations for specific arguments to functions.

Comment: The first axis is the samples (batch size), that's why it sums over the dataset.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro How does the `input_shape` effects the computation then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `input_shape` is the shape of **one** sample of the batch.
It doesn't matter if you have 200 or 10000 samples in a batch, all the samples should be (2,3).

But **the batch** itself is what is passed along from one layer to another.
A batch contains "n" samples, each sample with the `input_shape`:

- Batch shape then is: (n, 2, 3) -- n samples, each sample with input_shape = (2,3)

You don't define "n" when `input_shape` is required, because "n" will be defined when you use `fit` or another training command, with the `batch_size`. (In your example, n = 2)

---

This is the original array:

```
[[[ 0  1  2]
  [ 3  4  5]]

 [[ 6  7  8]
  [ 9 10 11]]]

Sample 1 = [ 0  1  2], [ 3  4  5]
Sample 2 = [ 6  7  8], [ 9 10 11]
```

Summing on index 0 (the batch size dimension) will sum sample 1 with sample 2:

```
[ 6 8 10], [12 14 16]
```

Summing on index 1 will sum the first dimension of **one sample's** input shape:

```
[ 3, 5, 7 ], [15, 17, 19]
```